# Change the Theme of Doxygen?

Tags: c, documentation, doxygen

I don't really think the Doxygen HTML theme for documenting C code is good for documenting functions and procedures (though it is awesome for documenting OOP if using C++). So what I'm asking is can the output be changed to resemble the [SDL Documentation](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/index.html) or [GTK Documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/)?

Comment: Those two pages look quite different to each other. You are probably more likely to get useful answers if you could edit your question to say which aspects of those other pages you want to see in your Doxygen output.

Comment: For a complete overview of options to customize the doxygen output, see
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html.

Answer (score 3):

Doxygen allows you to set a few options that control the look of the output. generally they start with `HTML_`. For maximum flexibility, you can provide custom header and footer HTML, as well as a custom CSS stylesheet, via the `HTML_HEADER`, `HTML_FOOTER` and `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET` options.

You can't do much to control the structure used in the main part of the page, but you can do a fair bit with the stylesheet, and as a last resort you can always add some javascript to the header that manipulates the DOM to rearrange things.

You can generate template header, footer and stylesheet files with the `-w` argument; and all this is documented reasonably well in the template config file generated with the `-g` argument.

Comment: Quoting from Doxygen's documentation: "It is recommended to use `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET` instead of `HTML_STYLESHEET`, as it is more robust, and this tag (HTML_STYLESHEET) will in the future become obsolete."
See: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_html_stylesheet

Answer (score 2):

The following theme allows the user to modify the color pattern, and the design is good.

https://github.com/kcwongjoe/doxygen_theme_flat_design